# llegal JSON value for key 'deviceProvisioningRealm': null while running wladm

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

When running the **Worklight Admin command line tool**, version `6.3.0.00.20141127-1357`, against same version server, I am receiving an error. This occurs when running the "list apps" command and a few other app-specific queries.

```
/app/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/shortcuts/wladm --configfile=/app/IBM/bldsrvwladmconfig.txt
```

> Error accessing
>   http://localhost:9080/worklightadmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/worklight/applications?pageSize=1000000000&locale=en_US:
>   HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error FWLSE3000E: A server error was
>   detected. Illegal JSON value for key 'deviceProvisioningRealm': null

Getting the content of the URL directly successfully returns data.

APAR PI33197 references a similar error, but without explanation of the cause or solution.

authenticationConfig.xml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <tns:loginConfiguration xmlns:tns="http://www.worklight.com/auth/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM 5725-G92 (C) Copyright IBM Corp.
                2006, 2013. All Rights Reserved. US Government Users Restricted Rights -
                Use, duplication or disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with
                IBM Corp. -->
        <staticResources>
            <resource id="subscribeServlet" securityTest="SubscribeServlet">
                            <urlPatterns>/subscribeSMS*;/receiveSMS*;/ussd*</urlPatterns>
                    </resource>
        </staticResources>
        <securityTests>
            <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
                <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" step="1"/>
                <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="SubscribeServlet"/>
            </customSecurityTest>
            <customSecurityTest name="ISAMforWorklight-web-securityTest">
                    <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" />
                    <test realm="WASLTPARealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
             </customSecurityTest>
            <customSecurityTest name="ISAMforWorklight-Step-up-securityTest">
                <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" step="1"/>
                <test isInternalDeviceID="false" isInternalUserID="true" realm="WASLTPARealm"/>
        </customSecurityTest>
        </securityTests>
        <realms>
             <realm loginModule="WASLTPAModule" name="WASLTPARealm">
                    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereFormBasedAuthenticator</className>
                    <parameter name="login-page" value="/login.html"/>
                    <parameter name="error-page" value="/loginError.html"/>
            </realm>
            <realm loginModule="rejectAll" name="SubscribeServlet">
                <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>
            </realm>
            <realm name="WorklightConsole" loginModule="requireLogin">
                    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
                    <onLoginUrl>/console</onLoginUrl>
            </realm>
            <realm name="deviceProvisioningRealm" loginModule="rejectAll">
                    <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>
            </realm>
        </realms>
        <loginModules>
            <loginModule name="rejectAll">
                <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule</className>
            </loginModule>
            <loginModule name="WASLTPAModule">
                            <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereLoginModule</className>
                    </loginModule>
        </loginModules>
    </tns:loginConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

This APAR has been fixed in version 6.3.0.00.20150305-1844.  Please download the latest fix available at [Fix Central.](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/)  Our fixes are cumulative so the latest fix will include the fix for this APAR.

Comment: The APAR mentions that editing authenticationConfig.xml resolved the issue. Can I find out details of that resolution?

Comment: If you upload the authenticationConfig.xml, we can help review and advise.  This might contain some sensitive info so it is best if you could submit a PMR and we can help you with this.  May I ask why you are not able to install the latest fix?

Comment: Installing the latest fix would need to be done on 20+ runtimes across all our environments, a QA regression cycle, etc. It just is not a small effort. Will upload a sanitized authconfig.